# How can i develop some ViewControllers graphically and then call them from a Cocos2d Iphone 2 scene?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uikit

I am new in the cocos2d world.

I am developing a simple game that also has a FORM where several users will fill their contact info (is a game for an event).

The form has to save data in sqlite or in NSUserDefaults array and then when the ipad gets connected to Wifi the user will sync all data to a mySQL using a REST service.

My question is:
Can i start a Cocos2d Project with its template and also add a soryboard or something to develop the non game's part as a usal ViewController?

I saw some posts about using a storyboard and then call the game Scene ass a Segue, but i think it might be better having my main menu and game Scene as Cocos2d Scenes and for the user input call a ViewController that then returns to my Scene (something similar to the Cocos2d iphone 2 project template that calls a ViewController from the Gamekit).

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
MYViewController *vc = [[MYViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Myview" bundle:nil];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:vc];
```

try this code to add view controller